# Переклад слова "конусообразная"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Маю речення

> *Ель сизая ‘Conica’ (Коника) - популярный сорт с густой, компактной
>   правильной конусообразной кроной.*

[Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)  подає такий переклад слова ***"конусообразная"***

> ф. конусообразная – ф. конусува́та

Проте слова "конусувата" немає в СУМ-11

Мій варіант перекладу

> Ялина сиза 'Conica' (Коніка) - популярний сорт з густою, компактною
>   правильною ***"конусовидной"*** кроной.

Але слово "конусовидна" також немає в СУМ-11, лише на сайті [Словник.ua](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0) є слово "конусовидний".

Як правильно зробити переклад слова "конусообразная"?

Comment: Конусоподібна, я так думаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

СУМ-20 містить:

- **[коні́чний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43527&page=1375)**;
- [ко́нусний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43808&page=1385);
- [конусо́вий](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43810&page=1385) ([«Словники України он-лайн» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) і [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/pages/04/sum_04_270_2.gif) дають для цього слова подвійний наголос: *ко́нусо́вий*);
- [конусоподі́бний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43811&page=1385).